# Generalized likelihood test question

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, likelihood-ratio

This example appears in Rice's stats book.

1. In the first rectangle, why do we have to maximize the denominator? and why do we use MLE as the denominator to maximize it? I know that MLE best reduces the mean squared error, but I am not clear about why we have to maximize the denominator using MLE when we test the likelihood of $H_1$, which is the unspecified counter hypothesis of $H_0$.

   My guess is that, the denominator likelihood is the likelihood of counter hypothesis against $H_0$, which is not specified, so it includes all the other possibility other than the one in $H_0$. Among these all possibilities, MLE produces the largest likelihood, so we regard MLE as the compatible likelihood to the one of all the other possibilities. Please correct me if I am wrong.
2. In the second rectangle, how was this identity established?

   I tried to extend the equation, but never get to the point where RH and LH are equal.

[image]

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I revised the question. This is the first time that I use stats exchange, so I am sorry for my ignorance!

Comment: There is no need to apologize. Thank you for adding the tag, please be sure to read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 2):

The MLE in the Normal case minimizes the mean-squared error but not always. For instance, in the Laplace distribution the MLE, which is the sample median, minimizes the mean absolute error. In general, the MLE maximizes the joint distribution of your observed sample and this may be done in a number of ways.

Having said, I believe that you have grasped the intuition behind the LRT. Since we like our likelihood to be large, we compare likelihoods under different scenarios and reject the null hypothesis if the ratio is too small.

Now, when it comes to the identity

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \left( X_i - \mu \right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \bar{X} \right)^2 + n \left( \bar{X} - \mu \right)^2 $$

why don't you try adding and subtracting $\bar{X}$ inide the square in the LHS before expanding?

Hint: $$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \bar{X} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - n \bar{X} = ?$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Considering the second equation you gave results 0, now I can see that I can interchange $\bar{X}$ and $X_i$ within the summation over all $N$. Thinking in that way, the first term in the RHS of your first equation is zero, and I by switching  $\bar{X}$ to $X_i$ and adding summation instead of n-times, the RHS and LHS are the same. Can I think it in this way? Or, is there any more intuitive interpretation regarding this identity?

Comment: @AnnDescomp I don't really understand what you mean by "interchange" the sample mean and $X_i$. The intuition behind the identity is the decomposition of population mean deviation into deviations from the sample mean and deviations of the sample mean from the population mean.

Comment: what I meant was that I can substitute sample mean and $X_i$ within the summation in this case because the sums of them are identical.